# why is a double-quoted awk command substitution failing in csh

Tags: awk, csh, tcsh

Using C shell, the following command-line

```
set pf = "`awk -v var=$pd '{if($1<0) print var, $2, $3}' test.txt`"
```

returns an error in awk:

```
awk： {if( <0) print var, , } syntax error.
```

This is especially puzzling as the command itself works without any problem:

```
awk -v var=$pd '{if($1<0) print var, $2, $3}' test.txt
```

Is there a way that we can store all output of the single Awk command line into a single variable? What is the reason the above is failing?

Comment: Welcome to SO, since I don't have `csh` with me so can't test it. For initial trouble shooting can you please run only `awk` command and see what error are you getting?

Comment: no problem for the single use of awk in the command line (awk -v var=$pd '{if($1<0) print var, $2, $3}' test.txt)

Comment: Could you please try following once `set pf=$(awk -v var=$pd '{if($1<0) print var, $2, $3}' test.txt)` and let me know then?

Comment: it cant work. The syntax is right for your command?

Comment: I have already mentioned I don't have `csh` so it is only guess, note this worked on BASH, could you please try and let me know then.

Comment: what form of csh are you running? tcsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, I can only come to the conclusion that it is one of those C-Shell quirks. C-shell (`csh` or `tcsh`) is apparently notoriously known for its [peculiarities](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/), and I believe that this is exactly what is going on here. Here are some examples, based on the OP's enigma.

**unquoted:**

```
$ set a = `echo a_b c | awk '{print $1}'` ; echo $a
a_b
$ set a = `echo a_b c | awk '{print $1,2}'` ; echo $a
a_b 2
$ set a = `echo a_b c | awk '{print $1 OFS 2}'` ; echo $a
a_b 2
```

**quoted:**

```
$ set a = "`echo a_b c | awk '{print $1}'`" ; echo $a
a_b c
$ set a = "`echo a_b c | awk '{print $1,2}'`" ; echo $a
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,2}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
$ set a = "`echo a_b c | awk '{print $1 OFS 2}'`" ; echo $a
2
```

So, in the double-quoted examples, it looks like `$1` is replaced by an empty string. This explains why the first case prints the full line `a_b c` and the third just the number `2`. The second fails as the Awk statement `print ,2` is invalid while the first works as `print` is equivalent to `print $0` in Awk.

If you play a bit more, you actually notice that C-shell tries to do variable substitution. You actually do not need to use `set` in all the above, just a simple double-quoted command substitution. The following example shows completely how bananas this is:

```
$ echo $0
csh
$ echo "`echo a_b c | awk '{print $0}'`"

$ echo "`echo a_b c | awk -v csh=foo '{print $0}'`"
foo
$ echo `echo a_b c | awk -v csh=foo '{print $0}'`
a_b c
```

So from this, you see that C-Shell is performing the variable substitutions and `$0` is being replaced with the string `csh`. **But only in the double-quoted version!**

**So, why is this the case?** The reason is the double-quotes. A double-quoted string allows variable substitution, disregarding the usage of nested quotes within the double-quoted string. So, even though, the Awk line is single-quoted in a back-wards quoted string, the double-quotes still will do the variable substitution on `$n`. This is in contrast to Bash:

```
$ echo $0
bash
$ echo "`echo a_b c | awk -v csh=foo '{print $0}'`"
a_b c
```

> **Lexical structure**
>
> Furthermore, all *Substitutions* (see below) except History substitution can be prevented by enclosing the strings (or parts of strings) in which they appear with single quotes or by quoting the crucial character(s)  (e.g., `$` or `` ` `` for Variable substitution or Command substitution respectively) with `\`.  (Alias substitution is no exception: quoting in any way any character of a word for which an alias has been defined prevents substitution of the
>          alias.  The usual way of quoting an alias is to precede it with a backslash.) History substitution is prevented by backslashes but not by single quotes.  ***Strings quoted with double or backward quotes undergo Variable substitution and Command substitution, but other substitutions are prevented.***
>
> Quoting complex strings, particularly strings which themselves contain quoting characters, can be confusing.  Remember that quotes need not be used as they are in human writing!  It may be easier to quote not an entire string, but only those parts of the string which need quoting, using different types of quoting to do so if appropriate.
>
> <sub>**source: `man csh`**</sub>

**So, how can this be solved?** While C-shell is completely non-intuitive and mentally a quoting nightmare, it is possible to fix the problem by terminating the quoting early and change from double to single-quotes for a short time.

```
$ echo "`echo a_b c | awk -v csh=foo '{print "'$0,$1'"}'`"
a_b c a_b
$ echo "`echo a_b c | awk -v csh=foo '"'{print $0,$1}'"'`"
a_b c a_b
```

**Solution:** So after all this, I think we can conclude that

```
$ set pf = "`awk -v var=$pd '"'{if($1<0) print var, $2, $3}'"' test.txt`"
```

could potentially solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, in some cases you are right. But this answer is not the exact one what I want. I do need to realise the code given in the question. If it cannot work, please give a definite answer to that code. Thanks.

Comment: your answer  is not the right answer. The reason why I use double quote is to get the whole table of the data(you can try that with other mission like more in the double quotes). I wanna get the exact answer for if or not the awk mission can be used in the double quotes. If it can be used in the double quotes, how to use that successfully. If not, please give a clear answer for why.

Comment: Thanks kavantour for your drilling. The solution seems a little weird. Maybe that's the weakness of Cshell. Anyway, it solves the problem. As for your comments, I am considering to use Bshell intead:-) Thanks all the time.Regards.